# Fatal Exception:main

Tags: android, program-entry-point, fatal-error

I am having a little trouble. I am completely new at this. I am trying to get my app to start with a splash screen then continue on to a new activity, but my app keeps force closing with a fatal exception:main. this is the logcat

```
02-12 02:56:32.989: D/AndroidRuntime(1487): Shutting down VM
02-12 02:56:32.989: W/dalvikvm(1487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e560)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.madonk.LAFEST/com.madonk.LAFEST.MAIN}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1716)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.madonk.LAFEST.MAIN.onCreate(MAIN.java:17)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
02-12 02:56:33.009: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     ... 11 more
```

If there is anything anyone can do to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Could you post your source? All the console tells me is that there is a problem with a ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity probably extends `ListActivity` and because of this in your `xml` file containing the layout of your activity(the one you set with `setContentView(R.layout.name_of_layout`)) you must have a `ListView` element with the id:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
//other attributes
>
```

Comment: @ShashankKadne Yes because a `ListView` is the default layout for the `ListActivity` so there is no need for `setContentView` if all you want is a list, but he probably set the content view to customize the layout and in this case he must have the `ListView` element with the id `@android:id/list`.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you. Now I'm cooking with Crisco!

Comment: (+1) Ohk...thnks for d info...:)

Comment: What I'd like is a splash screen that displays the name of the app, then to go to an activity that will display a list, and later on, some options and ads (to make my time worth it of course.) I would like the list to be clickable to display information in a new activity.

Comment: @Madonk:I think you should ask a separate question for this.