# FATAL EXCEPTION:main &Other logcat errors?

Tags: java, android, xml, logcat

Ive created a button that needs to be pressed and it was working for a while but now the program crashes every time its pressed.

Heres my logcat: http://pastebin.com/CvJvLmfs

Thanks, all help appreciated.

Btw. I also found this [Fatal Exception:main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247327/fatal-exceptionmain) although I havent extended List Activity?Thanks again.

Comment: have you tried cleaning & rebuilding the project? if that doesn't work, post the code in the buttons onClick listener & initialization here so we can see what you're doing

Comment: Thanks for your response through a process of trial and error I came upon the line of code that caused the problem and realized I was attempting to pass an integer argument to TextView.